# How to select a string in list view

Tags: c#

How to select an string item that is available in listview using the same string, like,

```
listView1.Focus();
listView1.Items["test"].Selected = true;
```

"test" is already available in listview...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListViewItem item1 = listView1.FindItemWithText("test");
if (item1 != null)
     item1.Selected = true;
```